# Run and edit a Perl/Python/non-Powershell - Script in Powershell_ISE (Windows Server)

Tags: windows, script, perl, powershell-ise

I am on a Windows Server (2012) with Powershell_ISE and befor installing additional software I wanted to edit and test a script in the Powershell_ISE (it's a better *native* solution than using notepad + cmd.exe because of tabbed editing for example)

Idea: Keyboard Shortcut to a menu-entry (under "Add-Ons" in the menu) where the *perl.exe* is called with the current script-path as parameter.

I tried the following lines:

```
$psISE.CurrentPowerShellTab.AddOnsMenu.Submenus.Add("Perl",{$cur=$psISE.CurrentFile; saps "c:\strawberry\perl\bin\perl.exe" $cur.FullPath },'Ctrl+Alt+q')
```

(with saps=start-process) or

```
$psISE.CurrentPowerShellTab.AddOnsMenu.Submenus.Add("Perl",{$cur=$psISE.CurrentFile; & "c:\strawberry\perl\bin\perl.exe" $cur.FullPath },'Ctrl+Alt+e')
```

(with & = execute external command) or

```
$psISE.CurrentPowerShellTab.AddOnsMenu.Submenus.Add("Perl",{$cur=$psISE.CurrentFile; saps "c:\strawberry\perl\bin\perl.exe" $cur.FullPath -wait },'Ctrl+Alt+w')
```

(start-process and wait)

A cmd-Window is shortly flashing but in the console-pane there is no output.
(the Perlscript just prints "test" and is working when executed directly by running: `& "c:\strawberry\perl\bin\perl.exe" $cur.FullPath` in the console-pane)

If this would work, you could add this line to the $profile of the Powersehll_ISE to edit/execute scripts of all languages by calling the appropriate binary

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One minute later I tried the following line (with `&` in combination with `-wait` and it works:

```
$psISE.CurrentPowerShellTab.AddOnsMenu.Submenus.Add("Perl-Menu_Entry",{$cur=$psISE.CurrentFile; & "c:\strawberry\perl\bin\perl.exe" $cur.FullPath -wait },'Ctrl+Alt+y')
```

(you can use the "F"-Keys, too - e.g.: instead of 'ctrl+alt+y' just use 'F4')

To save the file before executing add `$psise.CurrentFile.Save()` to the line:

```
$psISE.CurrentPowerShellTab.AddOnsMenu.Submenus.Add("Perl-Menu_Entry",{$psise.CurrentFile.Save(); $cur=$psISE.CurrentFile; & "c:\strawberry\perl\bin\perl.exe" $cur.FullPath -wait },'Ctrl+Alt+y')
```